# Changing list item number/dots color with execCommand in contentEditable?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, contenteditable, execcommand

im trying to change the color of my text in a contentEditable div. I do this with the following code:

> ```
>     document.execCommand( 'styleWithCSS', false, true );
>     document.execCommand( 'foreColor', false, color );
> ```

This works pretty good. But if i try to do this in a `<ul>` or `<ol>` this is my ouput:

```
<ul><li><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">abc</span></li><li><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">def</span></li><li><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">ghi</span></li></ul>
```

as u can see it wraps the text but not the `<li>` so the dots/numbers wont change color.

How can i include the dots/numbers in the list so that they too change colors?

This is done in Angular 2 so preferably a solution in this context. JS would also work

Comment: What did you do @Martijn van den Bergh? Thanks!